# Get Running Total of each year + previous year's closing value from different column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to sum each year's quantity but I also want to add previous year's closing quantity in this sum.

Following is the sample dataset.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmpTable
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable (
    FinancialYear varchar(max),
    Date date,
    ItemName varchar(255),
    InQTY int,
    ClosingQTY int)

INSERT INTO #tmpTable (FinancialYear, Date, ItemName, InQTY, ClosingQTY) VALUES
('2021-22', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-04-05', 120), 'ItemA', 5, 5),
('2021-22', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-05-17', 120), 'ItemA', 3, 7),
('2021-22', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-11-09', 120), 'ItemA', 2, 9),
('2021-22', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2022-02-25', 120), 'ItemA', NULL, 7),
('2022-23', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2022-04-02', 120), 'ItemA', 2, 9),
('2022-23', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2022-11-01', 120), 'ItemA', 3, 11),
('2022-23', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2022-12-14', 120), 'ItemA', 4, 15)
GO

SELECT * FROM #tmpTable
```

Sample Table:

```
╔═══════════════╤════════════╤══════════╤═══════╤════════════╗
║ FinancialYear │ Date       │ ItemName │ InQTY │ ClosingQTY ║
╠═══════════════╪════════════╪══════════╪═══════╪════════════╣
║ 2021-22       │ 2021-04-05 │ ItemA    │ 5     │ 5          ║
╟───────────────┼────────────┼──────────┼───────┼────────────╢
║ 2021-22       │ 2021-05-17 │ ItemA    │ 3     │ 7          ║
╟───────────────┼────────────┼──────────┼───────┼────────────╢
║ 2021-22       │ 2021-11-09 │ ItemA    │ 2     │ 9          ║
╟───────────────┼────────────┼──────────┼───────┼────────────╢
║ 2021-22       │ 2022-02-25 │ ItemA    │ NULL  │ 7          ║
╟───────────────┼────────────┼──────────┼───────┼────────────╢
║ 2022-23       │ 2022-04-02 │ ItemA    │ 2     │ 9          ║
╟───────────────┼────────────┼──────────┼───────┼────────────╢
║ 2022-23       │ 2022-11-01 │ ItemA    │ 3     │ 11         ║
╟───────────────┼────────────┼──────────┼───────┼────────────╢
║ 2022-23       │ 2022-12-14 │ ItemA    │ 4     │ 15         ║
╚═══════════════╧════════════╧══════════╧═══════╧════════════╝
```

I tried "Over (Partition By )" to get each year's running sum.

```
SELECT a.FinancialYear, a.Date, a.ItemName, a.InQTY, a.ClosingQTY 
,SUM(a.InQTY)  OVER (PARTITION BY a.ItemName, a.FinancialYear  ORDER BY a.Date) [RunningInQTY]
FROM #tmpTable a
```

But I am not able to find a way to add previous year's closing QTY which is lying in another column and last row before beginning of new year.

Following is the expected result (marked in red box)

[image: Required Output]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors (or text for your post) when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Larnu the data is already there in text format, as is a DDL with consumable data, and the query in text format. The image only supplements this with a further explanation of the issue and for me at least it actually makes the issue clearer so I don't see a problem with the image in this post

Comment: So the image isn't needed? Then please remove it as it isn't helpful and could easily attract downvotes and/or close votes, as images of text, data, your question, etc *aren't* helpful.

Comment: The image may not be 100% necessary because the problem is still explained in words, but just because something isn't absolutely necessary doesn't mean it doesn't add to the question and should be deleted. For me, it provides a clarity on what the actual calculation the OP is doing, and highlights cells in a way that is perhaps less easily explained as words. I don't see why this would attract close votes or down votes, it is a perfectly good question. I 100% agree that *only* images of code/data is not helpful, but I don't think it does any harm to add in addition to text

Comment: Because the OP has text showing their attempt in the image, @GarethD . That is [severely frowned upon by the community](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), and I can't see anywhere in the question where their expected result isn't an image; which doesn't help those who can't access the image.

Comment: Fair enough on the expected result, but their attempt is already in the question. I appreciate that images of code/data are frowned upon by the community, but it is not a blanket rule of any post with an image in deserves a downvote, or that any image must either be an image of code/data and frowned upon or be redundant. Given the quantity of bad questions on the site, I tend to try and appreciate those that show  effort - and I like any question with DDL and sample data - even if they are not quite perfect.  I appreciate that is subjective though, so will agree to disagree on this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first row of each financial year you can identify the previous ClosingQTY using `LAG`, which leads to an expression something like:

```
CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FinancialYear ORDER BY Date) = 1 
        THEN LAG(ClosingQTY, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY Date) 
     ELSE 0 
 END
```

And if you add this to your sample data you end with:

| FinancialYear | Date | ItemName | InQTY | ClosingQTY | ClosingQTY2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-22 | 2021-04-05 | ItemA | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 2021-22 | 2021-05-17 | ItemA | 3 | 7 | 0 |
| 2021-22 | 2021-11-09 | ItemA | 2 | 9 | 0 |
| 2021-22 | 2022-02-25 | ItemA | NULL | 7 | 0 |
| 2022-23 | 2022-04-02 | ItemA | 2 | 9 | **7** |
| 2022-23 | 2022-11-01 | ItemA | 3 | 11 | 0 |
| 2022-23 | 2022-12-14 | ItemA | 4 | 15 | 0 |

Then you can simply get your desired result by summing this new column in a windowed function. You'll need to use a subquery, because you can't put one windowed function inside of another so your final query would be something like:

```
SELECT  t.FinancialYear,
        t.Date,
        t.ItemName,
        t.InQTY,
        t.ClosingQTY,
        RunningInQTY = SUM(t.InQTY) OVER(PARTITION BY t.FinancialYear ORDER BY t.Date),
        Running = SUM(ClosingQTY2 + t.InQTY) OVER(PARTITION BY t.FinancialYear ORDER BY t.Date)
FROM    (   SELECT *,
                    ClosingQTY2 = CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FinancialYear ORDER BY Date) > 1 THEN 0
                                       ELSE LAG(ClosingQTY, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY Date) 
                                   END
            FROM #tmpTable
        ) AS t
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!!

```
SELECT DATE, INQTY, CLOSINGQTY, 
FINANCIALYEAR,SUM(INQTY_NEW)  OVER (PARTITION BY FinancialYear  ORDER BY Date) AS ROLL_SUM
FROM (
select  DATE, INQTY, CLOSINGQTY, 
FINANCIALYEAR,
CASE WHEN FINANCIALYEAR<>(LAG(FINANCIALYEAR) OVER (ORDER BY FINANCIALYEAR)) THEN NVL(INQTY,0)+NVL(LAG(CLOSINGQTY) OVER (ORDER BY FINANCIALYEAR),0) ELSE INQTY END AS INQTY_NEW
FROM TABLE);
```

Result:

[image]

Improve "Financial year equality" by using Regex and check year=year-1 if you need.

Comment: What NVL ?  NVL(INQTY,0)

Comment: NVL is Null to Value. Since NULL + number = NULL so apply this to make it zero. Check for COALESCE if your DB has no NVL function.

Comment: What would be the meaning of  "Financial year equality" by using Regex and check year=year-1, seem interesting

Comment: I am using FINANCIALYEAR<>(LAG(FINANCIALYEAR) OVER (ORDER BY FINANCIALYEAR)). if you want to check only the previous year, you can get YYYY from YYYY-YY and check. Upto your data.